# CardPlayer Card not loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, cocoapods

In the Cards project, https://github.com/PaoloCuscela/Cards I downloaded the application and ran it and I encountered one problem with the CardPlayer Card. It is not loaded when view is loaded. 
If one clicks in the white area where the card should be it pops up and is then visible. Seems that the card infos are not being loaded.

When The View Loads

[image]

When the area the card should load in is tapped

[image]

This is what the debugger console says

```
Loaded!
CARDS: Something wrong with the video source URL
CARDS: Something wrong with the video source URL
2019-02-27 23:08:50.208 Demo[1841:237619] Failed to set (icon) user 
defined inspected property on (Cards.CardPlayer): [<Cards.CardPlayer 
0x15d7c6a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value 
coding-compliant for the key icon.
Loaded!
2019-02-27 23:08:55.120 Demo[1841:237619] <UIVisualEffectView 
0x15e7da20> is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the 
effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1.
```

Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

Update: Card Layout Function

```
 override open func layout(animating: Bool = true) {
    super.layout(animating: animating)

    let gimme = LayoutHelper(rect: backgroundIV.bounds)

    let aspect1016 = backgroundIV.bounds.width *  (10/16)
    let aspect921 = backgroundIV.bounds.width *  (9/21)
    let move = ( aspect1016 - aspect921 ) * 2

    subtitleLbl.transform = isPresenting ? 
CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: move) : CGAffineTransform.identity
    backgroundIV.frame.size.height = originalFrame.height + ( 
isPresenting ? move/2 : 0 )
    // Issue is here: Line 208
    let currentHeigh = backgroundIV.frame.size.height
    backgroundIV.frame.size.height = originalFrame.height + ( 
isPresenting ? move/2 : 0 )

    if backgroundIV.frame.size.height <= 0 {
        print ("heigh is 0")
        backgroundIV.frame.size.height = currentHeigh
    }
    player.view.frame.origin = CGPoint.zero
    player.view.frame.size = CGSize(width: backgroundIV.bounds.width, 
height: isPresenting ? aspect1016 : aspect921 )
    playerCoverIV.frame = player.view.bounds


    playPauseV.center = player.view.center
    playIV.center = 
playPauseV.contentView.center.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 
LayoutHelper.Width(5, of: playPauseV), y: 0))

    categoryLbl.frame.origin.y = gimme.Y(3, from: player.view)
    titleLbl.frame.origin.y = gimme.Y(0, from: categoryLbl)
    titleLbl.sizeToFit()

    categoryLbl.frame = CGRect(x: insets,
                               y: gimme.Y(3, from: player.view),
                               width: gimme.X(80),
                               height: gimme.Y(5))

    titleLbl.frame = CGRect(x: insets,
                            y: gimme.Y(0, from: categoryLbl),
                            width: gimme.X(70),
                            height: gimme.Y(12))
    titleLbl.sizeToFit()

    subtitleLbl.frame = CGRect(x: insets,
                               y: gimme.RevY(0, height: gimme.Y(14)) - 
insets,
                               width: gimme.X(80),
                               height: gimme.Y(12))
}


//MARK: - Actions

public func play() {

    player.playFromCurrentTime()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.playPauseV.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 
0.1)
        self.playPauseV.alpha = 0
    }
}

public func pause() {

    player.pause()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
        self.playPauseV.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        self.playPauseV.alpha = 1
    }
}

public func stop() {

    pause()
    player.stop()
}

@objc  func playTapped() {

    play()
    delegate?.cardPlayerDidPlay?(card: self)
}

@objc  func playerTapped() {

    pause()
    delegate?.cardPlayerDidPause?(card: self)
}

open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: 
UIEvent?) {
    if touches.first?.view == player.view || touches.first?.view == 
playPauseV.contentView { playerTapped() }
    else { super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event) }
}

}


// Player Delegates
extension CardPlayer: PlayerDelegate {
public func playerReady(_ player: Player) {

    player.view.addSubview(playPauseV)
    playPauseV.frame.size = CGSize(width: playBtnSize, height: 
playBtnSize)
    playPauseV.layer.cornerRadius = playPauseV.frame.height/2
    playIV.frame.size = CGSize(width: LayoutHelper.Width(50, of: 
playPauseV),
                               height: LayoutHelper.Width(50, of: 
playPauseV))
    playPauseV.center = player.view.center
    playIV.center = 
playPauseV.contentView.center.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 
LayoutHelper.Width(5, of: playPauseV), y: 0))

    if isAutoplayEnabled {

        play()
    } else {
        pause()
    }
}

public func playerPlaybackStateDidChange(_ player: Player) { }
public func playerBufferingStateDidChange(_ player: Player) { }
public func playerBufferTimeDidChange(_ bufferTime: Double) { }
}

extension CardPlayer: PlayerPlaybackDelegate {

public func playerPlaybackDidEnd(_ player: Player) {

    if shouldRestartVideoWhenPlaybackEnds { player.playFromBeginning() 
}
    else { playerTapped()  }

}

public func playerPlaybackWillLoop(_ player: Player) { }
public func playerCurrentTimeDidChange(_ player: Player) { }
public func playerPlaybackWillStartFromBeginning(_ player: Player) { }
}
```

**Solved** Added `backgroundIV.frame.size.height = 300` to 208 of CardPlayer.swift

Courtesy of @Shadowsheep in chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on [`CardPlayer.swift`](https://github.com/PaoloCuscela/Cards/blob/master/Cards/Sources/CardPlayer.swift) class, specifically under line `207` (`backgroundIV.frame.size.height = originalFrame.height + ( isPresenting ? move/2 : 0 )`)

When `controller` loads the `height` of `backgroundIV` is set to `0`.

Adding this check (under line `207`) should solve your problem.

```
// Issue is here
let currentHeight = backgroundIV.frame.size.height // <-- new line to store current value
/* this is line #207 */ backgroundIV.frame.size.height = originalFrame.height + ( isPresenting ? move/2 : 0 ) // This is line 207

// This is the check
if backgroundIV.frame.size.height <= 0 {
    print ("heigh is 0")
    backgroundIV.frame.size.height = currentHeight
}
```

This error instead

```
Failed to set (icon) user 
defined inspected property on (Cards.CardPlayer): [<Cards.CardPlayer 
0x15d7c6a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value 
coding-compliant for the key icon.
```

is related with a User Define Runtime Attribute set to the view in the `Main.storyboard` that doesn't belong to CardPlayer (you could remove it if you want)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added the check to line 207 and the problem seems to persist.

Comment: @user3233623 it shouldn't. I've tried and tested it. Maybe our files differs, I've checkout Card demo from GitHub today. Could you update your answer, showing where you put the check? You could also post the entire CardPlayer layout function.

Comment: @user3233623 Yep line is 207, you have to test after the first frame.size.height settings `backgroundIV.frame.size.height = originalFrame.height + ( isPresenting ? move/2 : 0 )` ;-). I've updated my answer. Put the check under this line `backgroundIV.frame.size.height = originalFrame.height + ( isPresenting ? move/2 : 0 )`

Comment: Okay. I edited with an update of the layout function.

Comment: @user3233623 see my other comments, you have to check after, not before this line `backgroundIV.frame.size.height = originalFrame.height + ( isPresenting ? move/2 : 0 )`

Comment: Thank you for the updates. I added the check to line 208 and am getting the same results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189186/discussion-between-shadowsheep-and-user3233623).